# Player heads linked to player skin id

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know it is possible to give a player head with say ID of whatever skin you want but, I want to make it give the player head with the precise skin at the time the player is killed. I just don't want when the skin has changed the head to change to the new skin I want it to preserve the current skin when you are killed.

For instance, if Player X has Skin A, it gives the player head with Skin A, but if it has Skin B, it gives Skin B.

So the question is can you test for which skin ID it is and can you pass that skin ID onto the give command?

I can work out most of the command myself but I am not sure if there any way to test which skin is on to retrieve that skin ID and then set that skin ID and the skull you give.

This one gives you how you give the specific head with certain skin [How to make custom player heads without making multiple accounts?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/287252/how-to-make-custom-player-heads-without-making-multiple-accounts) 
just not how you can find it.

Comment: That particular answer requires you to possess a skull item (or at least have it on the ground) in order to use `/entitydata` on it. Aquiring a skull item is described there as well, but I don't think this answer suits your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not, changing the id of the block is easy but is there any way to get the playerdata from command blocks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command to spawn in-game Player head?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307859/command-to-spawn-in-game-player-head)

Comment: @pppery This question seems to ask for a command to summon a player's head based on the *contemporary* skin (so it won't change when a player changes their skin afterwards), and your proposed duplicate doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Might I suggest [this](http://minecraft-heads.com/custom/heads) website that will help you to get `/give` commands for specific heads you want off a huge collection of heads, and you can submit custom heads and get the code anytime.

Here is an example, this command will always give the same head and isn't affixed to anyone's skin.

```
/give @p skull 1 3 {display:{Name:"Phoenix"},SkullOwner:{Id:"a25967e7-82fd-4594-9650-473e3b99d453",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvM2Q4NjA3MjFkMzZiYjliNzllZWY3ZTM5MGQzYzQ4MTRhZTU1MDhhODkyOTE5ODI1OWJkMTgyYmY3NjE4MGI1In19fQ=="}]}}}
```